# How to write a batch file to permanently append a list of directories without redundancies even though we invoke the batch multiple times?

Tags: batch-file, dos

Assume I want to permanently append the following list of directories (in a trimmed version for the sake of simplicity) to my system (as opposed to my local) `PATH` environment variable.

```
c:\company\dept\users
d:\school\teachers
e:\school\students
```

I have to do this by clicking a batch file (with admin privilege set on). If I am not sure I have already done it, I can do clicking the batch file again but without appending redundancies.

Shortly speaking, how can we write such a batch file? I guess we have to make a test for each item in the list whether or not it has been in the `PATH`. But how to do this?

What I have done so far is

```
setx PATH "%PATH%;c:\company\dept\users" /m
setx PATH "%PATH%;d:\school\teachers" /m
setx PATH "%PATH%;e:\school\students" /m
```

but it is not intelligent to prevent redundancies.

I have no knowledge to implement the redundancy test.

Comment: @NateHekman: See my last update please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general approach, I would suggest looking at `for` with a `delims=;` to split `%PATH%` on semicolons, then compare each part to the path you're considering adding.

If you have specific problems along the way, post them as new questions (or search--they may already be answered) and we'll be happy to answer more.

You can get documentation on the `for` loop by typing `help for` at the command line.

EDIT:  Here's a better answer, from the SuperUser forum: [Append to path without duplicating it](https://superuser.com/questions/480238/cmd-append-to-path-without-duplicating-it)

Comment: I will accept this if no other answer is available to compare. :-)

Comment: Did you see my edit?  It links to what I think is really your best answer.

Comment: Yes. I have visited the link. Thank you for the link.